# Fetched Object from API doesn't appear in mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I call a get request to my api, and then register them to my state with this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts()
},)

const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

const fetchPosts = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/posts/')
    const posts_data = await data.json()
    setPosts(posts_data)
}
```

I even tried the axios approach:

```
await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/posts/')
.then(res => {
    setPosts(res.data)
    console.log(posts)
})
```

If I console.log `posts_data` and `posts`, it gives me the Object I got from my api:

```
[{title: "Sample post", desc: "sample desc"}, {...}]
```

But whenever I iterate and display it:

```
<div>
    {posts.map(post => {
        <div>
            <p>{post.title}</p>
            <h1>asdjasdljaskldjs</h1>
        </div>
    })}
</div>
```

It doesn't show up on the page. I even tried adding that random string there `asdjasdljaskldjs` and it doesn't show too. The data is received and stored, but I wonder why it doesn't display.

## Entire component code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function Posts() {

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPosts()
    },)

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

    const fetchPosts = async () => {

        await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/posts/')
            .then(res => {
                setPosts(res.data)
                console.log(posts)
            })

        // const data = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/posts/')
        // const posts_data = await data.json()
        // setPosts(posts_data)
        // console.log(posts)
    }

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid col-lg-7 mt-3">
            <h1>POSTS</h1>
            <div>
                {posts.map(post => {
                    <div>
                        <p>{post.title}</p>
                        <h1>asdjasdljaskldjs</h1>
                    </div>
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Posts
```

I also noticed when I console.log the `posts_data` or `posts`, it keeps printing over and over again while you're on the page. Is that normal?
[image]

Comment: Please include all the code for the component in question.

Comment: Your component infinitely re-renders because your effect has no dependencies but eventually triggers a state change. For once-only effects you need something like: `useEffect(() => {/*...*/}, []);` Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: For infinite loop provide a second argument to useEffect. In your empty array [] would do. 
e.g useEffect(() => { fetchPosts()}, [] )
Refer: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mapping function isn't returning the JSX.  Change your return to:

```
return (
    <div className="container-fluid col-lg-7 mt-3">
        <h1>POSTS</h1>
        <div>
            {posts.map(post => (
                <div>
                    <p>{post.title}</p>
                    <h1>asdjasdljaskldjs</h1>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

You need to surround the returned JSX with parens, not `{}`, or you need a `return` before the `{}`.

Comment: You gotta be kidding me. Those parenthesis... THANK YOU SO MUCH!  God bless! :)